# PDF JS reactangle scaling

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

We are using PDF JS to render pdf document .We have a requirement where we want to persist all text highlight user is doing in the UI .
To solve this problem we are trying to pass rectangle information to the back which is coming out as part of text selection .
But I am not able to compute scaling factor correctly as a result the rectangle being drawn in pdf is bit off .
I am computing scalingFactor= (canvas.width)/page.getViewport(1.0).width

Am i doing it right ?

Comment: Could you create a demo page or jsfiddle? Right now it is not clear what you are doing. (I get de computation of the scale factor, but not what it is about)

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt In the UI I am painting the PDF JS canvas( which represents a PDF page) to simulate text highlighting after getting the  text selection coordinates .Now I want to pass this information to the  server side  so that i can redraw same rectangle on the PDF page whhich has been rendered using ApachePDFBox .Problem is my x,y,width and height offsets after applying scaling factor are comming off

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the scaling factor:

```
scalingFactor= (canvas.width)/page.getViewport(1.0).width
```

computes scaling from pdf document units to html canvas units.

So isn't this an issue of just having to invert the scaleFactor on the server?